# Highcharts - Tooltip width in styled mode

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

I am trying to set up a dynamic tooltip width in STYLED MODE.

I am trying to write a Tooltip wrapper, but have trouble figuring out which function I should wrap, can someone please advise?

Below is example of the approach

```
H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, 'theFunc', (p) => {
  const label = this.label;
    const width = this.chart.plotWidth < 300 ? 100 : 200;
    label.css({width: width+'px'});
})
```

**UPDATE:**
Result that I get when useHTML is set true

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to wrap any method, it is enough if you use `formatter` callback function:

```
    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function() {
            const chart = this.series.chart;
            const width = chart.plotWidth < 300 ? 100 : 200;

            return '<div style="width:' + width + 'px">' + this.y + '</div>'
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5kdonwbj/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: Appreciate your help, however solution didn't work for me for some reason. I just get an empty box in our project (added screenshot in the body of question)- I wonder if something else can interfere with tooltip settings? for the reference we are using highcharts 8.2.2

Comment: Hi @Sabira, The solution also works fine in version 8.2.2, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rkqvaf47/ Could you reproduce the problem in jsfiddle?

Comment: Hello, sorry, it was a css error and wasn't related to highcharts. Appreciate your help!